# several funcions in one dll or seperate?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have algorithm (c++ dll) wrapped in C#. The execution is on a web server. 
Considering throughput/speed/memory etc. Should i write all functions in one dll or each function one dll? which way is better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions, classes and other structures may contain in one dll. This is better option. If you create more dll for each functions, management of the project, implementation and maintanence will be harder.

Comment: will it be a problem when executing on the server with many concurrent requests?

Comment: Actually it depends on the server power. I have worked for eCommerce company in last year. Their project contains thounsands of functions, classes, structures and so on. But they have only one solution, and the solution contain 8 different projects. That means only one dll for each projects.